# $(r_n)$ is a positive sequence such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} r_n=\infty$.

Tags: functions, continuity

$(r_n)$ is a positive sequence such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} r_n=\infty$. For a continuous function $f$, $f(r_nx)=f(r_{n+1} x)$ for all real numbers $x$ and natural numbers $n$. Show that $f$ is a constant function.

Comment: How do you define a constant function?

Comment: For any x not equal to y, f(x)=f(y)

Answer (score 5):

Note that, by induction, $f(r_nx)=f(r_0x)$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$ and $x\in\Bbb R$. Let $a\in\Bbb R$ and $x_n=a/r_n$ ($n\in \Bbb N$). Then $$f(a)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(r_nx_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(r_0a/r_n)=f(0),$$because $r_n\to\infty$ and by the continuity of $f$. Since $a$ is arbitrary, $f$ is constant.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f$ be continous and $(r_n)\to\infty$. Provided the things in your post:

Assume by contradiction that $f$ is not constant. Then there exist $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ such that we can assume without loss of generality that $f(x) > f(y)$. Given that $x\neq y$ (which is obviously true), there then exist indices $p,q$ such that $x=: r_pa, y=: r_qb$ and $f(r_pa) > f(r_qb)$. The contraposition is hence also true.

Comment: a is not necessarily equal to b right?

Comment: Might be, what matters is $r_pa\neq r_qb$

Comment: Suppose f is not constant. One has to show that there exists some x and n, such that $f(r_nx) \neq f(r_{n+1} x)$. In your case, p=n, q=n+1, what about x?

Comment: The set $A:= \{n\in\mathbb{N}| f(r_nx) = f(r_{n+1}x)\}$ is inductive. Objective is to show that $f$ is constant. We prove this by assuming $f$ is not constant and showing that $A$ is not inductive. (proof by contradiction)  

in my case $p,q\in\mathbb{N}$ exist, I don't know anything about the relation between them.

Comment: The existence of these indices, however, is sufficient to violate inductivity of $A$